# to delete data in mongodb using angularjs and node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I want to delete data in mongodb using angularjs and node.js but Cannot DELETE /api/manage-product error is coming in console.

### .html file

```
<tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in vm.result">
                    <td>{{ product.Product_Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.Brand }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.Color }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.Price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.Rating }}</td>
                    <td><img style="heigth:30px; width:30px;" src='{{ product.Image }}'></img></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(product._id)">Remove</button></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

### controller.js

```
$scope.remove = function(object) {
        $http({ 
                url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product', 
                method: 'DELETE', 
                data: {_id: object.id}, 
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
        }).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res.data);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

### node.js

```
router.delete('/manage-product/:_id', function(req,res){

    var db = req.db;

    var _id = req.params._id.toString();
    var collection = db.get('proInfo');

    collection.remove({"_id":_id}, function(err, result) { 
        res.send( (result === 1) ? { msg: 'Deleted' } : { msg: 'error: '+ err } );
    });

});
```

[image: console error image]

Comment: Your `router` doesn't have the `/api/` prefix on the path?    Also, consider using `$resource` instead of `$http` for interfacing with RESTful services.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
  $http({ 
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product/'+object.id, 
            method: 'DELETE'  

    })
```

instead of

```
   $http({ 
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product', 
            method: 'DELETE', 
            data: {_id: object.id}, 
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code i fixed the problem.

### controller.js

```
     $scope.remove = function(_id,rindex) {     
        alert('Are you sure you want to delete?');
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{productId: _id}, 
        }).success(function(res) {
            console.log('another success');
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
    }
```

### node.js

```
router.post('/manage-product', function(req, res){
        console.log('I received another get request');

        var removeproducts = function(db, callback) {
           db.collection('proInfo').deleteOne({_id : ObjectId(req.body.productId)},
              function(err, results) {
                 console.log('product deleted');
                 callback();
              }
           );
        };

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);

          removeproducts(db, function() {
              db.close();
          });
        });         
    });
```